# How does DRM video Streaming happens under the hood?

Tags: azure, video-streaming, drm

I need to develop a system to stream media over the web to subscribers (like Netflix). It's very important that my consumers can't "save on disk" my videos, since I'll be billing them by the minute watched...

I would like to know how video-streaming-DRM software, like the one behind Netflix, actually work. How the encryption happens? Do they use symmetric keys? I don't need specifics about the implementation, not now at least, but rather a overview of the whole system (client and server)

Extra Info:
-I will be the one uploading videos. The user wont upload videos
-I intend to build this as a Azure Cloud Native App
-I have not yet decided on the client side yet. Since my target public is quite narrow, I'm considering if I should build a app client or web-client... in case of web I would like to leverage the new [DRM capabilities](http://arstechnica.com/business/2013/05/drm-in-html5-is-a-victory-for-the-open-web-not-a-defeat/) ...
-The server side will be C#
-It's safe to assume that the end-user will have a "decent 3º world" internet connection (at least 1 Mb/s)

Answer (score 2):

Although quite reasonable, your question does not really fit the [Stack Overflow's format](https://stackoverflow.com/faq). But I'll give you some hints and resources to check out:

- [Microsoft PlayReady Overview](http://www.microsoft.com/playready/overview/) - check it and related pages (like [Learn More](http://www.microsoft.com/playready/features/), [White Paper](http://www.microsoft.com/playready/documents/))
- [EZDRM](http://www.ezdrm.com/)
- [Content Protection with Windows Azure Media Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn223278.aspx)
- [Task Preset for Windows Azure Media Encryptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh973610.aspx)

Clients of DRM protected content can be developed in [Silverlgiht](http://smf.codeplex.com/), [Windows Store App](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e02ccac7-f3eb-4b53-b11a-c657d5631483), [iOS native app](https://www.microsoft.com/playready/licensing/) (this one is not open to the wide public!). Never tried Android and HTML 5.

In short - don't worry! If you use a DRM solution, your users will not be able to save the videos. However, one can always do a screen capture using [Expression Encoder Screen Capture | Camtasia Studio | Any screen capturing software]. So there is no full 100% content protection.